# Java Heap Space error is occurring

Tags: java, android, heap-memory

Java Heap Space error occurring in my system. I  tried lot of solutions from Stack Overflow but nothing is working.   When i am working

[image]

when pressing OK then 
[image]

[image]

(No error in my project)

My eclipse.ini Is:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

My RAM:4GB
 Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in eclipse.ini

```
 -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because Eclipse runs out of memory. What you can do is increase the allocated memory by editing (or creating) the `eclipse.ini` file (on a root of eclipse directory) and putting the following code:

```
-vmargs
-Xms512m (for 512 Mb)
-Xmx1024m (for 1024 Mb)
```

For a full list of available options, [please check this link](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html).

Comment: please tell me where to add those values

Comment: Ad a I said, into the `eclipse.ini` file on the root of your eclipse installation.

Answer (score 0):

you increase jvm memory in control panel. Its ok you have 4GB of memory but how much you have allocated for jvm to run is important let me know any further clarification.

Comment: pls  tell me how to know that how much memory has been allocated for jvm.

Comment: if you using windows go to control Panel - > java -> java tab --> View --> edit java run time parameters .. with some -jmx 1000 which say use 1000 mb for jvm .. but I suggest you check the syntex properly I dont remember it so.

Comment: That field is blank in my machine

Comment: I also suggest you go to your eclipse installation and edit eclipse.ini file with memory parameter. -Xms40m(minimum)
-Xmx1024m (maximum)